# Why does my saved images don't show correctly to right words [two textviews] in android using Room Database?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-cardview

I am working on a Flashcard app where there is a class QuestionsFragment.kt where there are 16 pairs of words along with their image in following manner. So in **QuestionsFragment** the data is displayed correctly in the cards but when I save one of the cards to learn it later and display it on other fragment called **ToLearnFlashcards** the cardviews displayed show incorrect image for the right pair of words. When I checked the Logcat, the data is being saved correctly. It's displaying incorrectly in following manner . [image: It shouldn't display this image]

Following is my QuestionsFragment,kt where I insert the data.

```
package com.example.visuallithuanian

import android.animation.*
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.res.ColorStateList
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.visuallithuanian.database.FlashcardPair
import com.example.visuallithuanian.databinding.FragmentQuestionsBinding
import com.example.visuallithuanian.ui.activities.FirstScreen
import com.example.visuallithuanian.viewModel.BottomNavigationViewModel
import com.example.visuallithuanian.viewModel.FlashCardViewmodel
import com.example.visuallithuanian.viewModel.ToLearnViewModel
import com.example.visuallithuanian.viewModel.WordViewModelFactory
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint


@AndroidEntryPoint
class QuestionsFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var binding:FragmentQuestionsBinding
    lateinit var viewModel: BottomNavigationViewModel

    lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView
    private val counterViewModel: ToLearnViewModel by viewModels()

    private val hashMap = HashMap<String,Pair<String,Int>>()

    private var currentPairIndex =0
    private lateinit var currentPair:Map.Entry<String,Pair<String,Int?>>

    var isFront=true
    private val totalPairs = 16 // change the value to the actual number of entries in your hashMap

    // declaring viewmodel
    private val cardViewModel: FlashCardViewmodel by viewModels {
        WordViewModelFactory((requireActivity().application as MyApp).repository)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentQuestionsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        bottomNavigationView = (activity as? FirstScreen)?.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)!!
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[BottomNavigationViewModel::class.java]


        bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE

        // setting up listener for back Icon
        binding.backIcon?.setOnClickListener {
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }

        binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_questionsFragment_to_flashCards)
        }

        //changing color of progress bar progress
        binding.progressHorizontal.progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext()
            ,R.color.blue_card))

        //changing color of background color of progress bar
        binding.progressHorizontal.progressBackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),
        R.color.silver))

        // Hashmap of strings that will shown on cardview front and back side
        hashMap["What"] = Pair("Kas", R.drawable.what)
        hashMap["When"] = Pair("Kai",R.drawable.`when`)
        hashMap["Where"] = Pair("Kur",R.drawable.where)
        hashMap["Who"] = Pair("Kas",R.drawable.who)
        hashMap["Whom"] = Pair("Kam",R.drawable.whom)
        hashMap["Why"] = Pair("Kodėl",R.drawable.why)
        hashMap["How"] = Pair("Kaip",R.drawable.how)
        hashMap["Which"] = Pair("Kuris/kuri",R.drawable.which)
        hashMap["Whose"] = Pair("Kieno",R.drawable.whose)
        hashMap["I"] = Pair("aš",R.drawable.i)
        hashMap["you (singular)"] = Pair("tu/jūs (informal/formal)",R.drawable.you)
        hashMap["he"] = Pair("jis",R.drawable.he)
        hashMap["she"] = Pair("ji",R.drawable.she)
        hashMap["we"] = Pair("mes",R.drawable.we)
        hashMap["you (plural)"] = Pair("jūs",R.drawable.you)
        hashMap["they"] = Pair("jie",R.drawable.they)

        counterViewModel.counter.observe(requireActivity()){count->
            binding.textCounter.text = count.toString()
        }
        val front_animation = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.anim.front_animator) as AnimatorSet
        val back_animation = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context,R.anim.back_animator)as AnimatorSet

        currentPair = hashMap.entries.elementAt(currentPairIndex)
        binding.textCardFront.text = currentPair.key
        binding.textCardBack.text = currentPair.value.first
        binding.imagecardsHelper.setImageResource(currentPair.value.second!!)

        // onclick listener on the image
        binding.imageFlashCard.setOnClickListener {
            val clickedColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.white)
            binding.imageFlashCard.setBackgroundColor(clickedColor)

            counterViewModel.incrementCounter()
            // increment currentPairIndex and get the next pair
            currentPairIndex++
            if (currentPairIndex >= hashMap.size) {
                // if we have reached the end of the hashmap, start again from the beginning
                currentPairIndex = 0
            }
            currentPair = hashMap.entries.elementAt(currentPairIndex)

            val front = binding.textCardFront.text.toString()
            val back = binding.textCardBack.text.toString()
            val imageHelper = currentPair.value.second

            val pair = FlashcardPair(front, back,imageHelper!!)
            cardViewModel.insertCards(pair)
            //Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"saved data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.d("Main","$pair")

            // update the UI with the new pair
            binding.textCardFront.text = currentPair.key
            binding.textCardBack.text =currentPair.value.first
            binding.imagecardsHelper.setImageResource(currentPair.value.second!!)



        }

        binding.cardLearning.setOnClickListener {

            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_questionsFragment_to_toLearnFlashCards)

        }

        //onclick listener for the Flip button
        with(binding) {
            btnFlip.setOnClickListener {
                val progress = ((currentPairIndex + 1) * 100) / totalPairs
                binding.progressHorizontal.progress = progress

                val originalColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.pink)
                binding.imageFlashCard.setBackgroundColor(originalColor)

                // initialize currentPairIndex to 0 if it hasn't been initialized yet
                if (currentPairIndex < 0) {
                    currentPairIndex = 0
                }
                if (isFront) {
                    front_animation.setTarget(textCardFront)
                    back_animation.setTarget(textCardBack)
                    front_animation.start()
                    back_animation.start()
                    isFront = false
                    textCardBack.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    textCardFront.visibility = View.GONE
                    imageFlashCard.visibility = View.GONE
                    cardViewQuestions.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.card_purple))

                } else {
                    currentPairIndex = (currentPairIndex + 1) % hashMap.size
                    textCardFront.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    textCardBack.visibility = View.GONE
                    imageFlashCard.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    cardViewQuestions.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.pink))
                    front_animation.setTarget(textCardBack)
                    back_animation.setTarget(textCardFront)
                    back_animation.start()
                    front_animation.start()
                    isFront = true
                }

                // add the following code to make the button shake
                val shake: ObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.btnFlip, "translationX", -10f, 10f)
                shake.duration = 100
                shake.repeatCount = 5
                shake.repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE
                shake.start()
                // retrieve the current pair from the hashMap
                currentPair = hashMap.entries.elementAt(currentPairIndex)
                binding.textCardFront.text = currentPair.key
                binding.textCardBack.text = currentPair.value.first
                binding.imagecardsHelper.setImageResource(currentPair.value.second!!)
            }
        }

        binding.cardLearning.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_questionsFragment_to_toLearnFlashCards)
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

The fragment [ToLearnFlashcards] where saved cardviews display as shown in the above image has this code.

```
package com.example.visuallithuanian


import com.example.visuallithuanian.custom.OverlappingLayoutManager
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.observe
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.visuallithuanian.adapter.FlashcardpaiAdapter
import com.example.visuallithuanian.databinding.FragmentToLearnFlashCardsBinding
import com.example.visuallithuanian.ui.activities.FirstScreen
import com.example.visuallithuanian.viewModel.FlashCardViewmodel
import com.example.visuallithuanian.viewModel.WordViewModelFactory
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView


class ToLearnFlashCards : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding:FragmentToLearnFlashCardsBinding
    lateinit var bottomNav:BottomNavigationView
    val cardViewmodel:  FlashCardViewmodel by viewModels{
        WordViewModelFactory((requireActivity().application as MyApp).repository)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentToLearnFlashCardsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)

        //Taking the bOTTOMNavigation view instance from Activity into Fragment
        bottomNav = (activity as? FirstScreen)?.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)!!
        bottomNav.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        // Bounce animation for emojiBounce view
        val bounceAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            binding.emojiBounce,
            "translationX",
            0f,
            -100f,
            0f
        ).apply {
            duration = 2000 // Set the duration of the animation
            repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE // Set the repeat count for infinite bouncing
            repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE // Reverse the animation after each repeat
        }

        // Start the bounce animation
        bounceAnimator.start()

        binding.backIcon.setOnClickListener {
           findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_toLearnFlashCards_to_flashCards)
        }

        val adapter = FlashcardpaiAdapter(
            onDeleteListener = {cardPair->
                cardViewmodel.insertCards(cardPair)
            },
            imageSrcListener = {cardPair->
                cardPair.imageSrc

            }
        )

        binding.recyclerview.adapter = adapter

        //Swipe Gesture

        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object :ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT
        ){
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }
            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                val cardPair = adapter.currentList[position]
                // Handle swipe left to delete the card
                cardViewmodel.deleteCards(cardPair)
            }
        })
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerview)

        binding.recyclerview.layoutManager = OverlappingLayoutManager(binding.root.context)
      //  binding.recyclerview.rotation=10f

        //Observe  the data changes for the items added
        cardViewmodel.allWords.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { cardPairs ->

                adapter.submitList(cardPairs)

                if (cardPairs.isEmpty()){
                    binding.emptyImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }else{
                    binding.emptyImage.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }

        return binding.root
    }

}
```

Following is the FlashcardpaiAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.visuallithuanian.adapter

import android.os.Build
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.visuallithuanian.R
import com.example.visuallithuanian.database.FlashcardPair

class FlashcardpaiAdapter(private val onDeleteListener:((FlashcardPair)->Unit),
                          private val imageSrcListener: (FlashcardPair) -> Int?
                          ) : ListAdapter<FlashcardPair,FlashcardpaiAdapter.WordViewHolder>(WordsComparator()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WordViewHolder {
        return WordViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WordViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = getItem(position)
       // val current1 = getItem(position)

        holder.bind(current.front,current.back,imageSrcListener.invoke(current))


        // Set different colors for alternate rows
        val colorRes = if (position % 2 == 0) {
            R.color.white // Color resource for even rows
        } else {
            R.color.white// Color resource for odd rows
        }
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(holder.itemView.context.getColor(colorRes))

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            //holder.left.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            //holder.right.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }



    }

    class WordViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val wordItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        private val deftext: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2)
        private val imageHelper = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageCardHelper)

        //val left = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textLeft)
        //val right = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textRight)

        fun bind(text: String?, text1: String?,imageSource:Int?) {
            wordItemView.text = text
            deftext.text=text1
            if (imageSource!= null) {
                imageHelper.setImageResource(imageSource)
            } else {
                // Set a default image if the imageSrc is null
                imageHelper.setImageResource(R.drawable.emoji)
            }

        }

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): WordViewHolder {
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.recycle_view, parent, false)
                return WordViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    class WordsComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<FlashcardPair>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem:FlashcardPair, newItem:FlashcardPair): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem:FlashcardPair, newItem:FlashcardPair): Boolean {
            return oldItem.front == newItem.front && oldItem.back==newItem.back
        }
    }
}
```

The data class is **FlashcardPair** and it has following code.

```
@Entity(tableName = "flashcards")
data class FlashcardPair(
    @PrimaryKey
    val front:String,
    val back:String,
    val imageSrc:Int
)
```

The Dao interface is FlashcardDao

```
@Dao
interface FlashCardDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM flashcards ORDER BY front ASC, back ASC")
    fun getAlphabetizedWords(): Flow<List<FlashcardPair>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertWord(pair: FlashcardPair)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteWord(pair: FlashcardPair)
    
}
```

The ViewModel class used to implement the observer is FlashCardviewmodel.kt

```
package com.example.visuallithuanian.viewModel

import androidx.lifecycle.*
import com.example.visuallithuanian.database.FlashcardPair
import com.example.visuallithuanian.repository.FlashcardRepository
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

class FlashCardViewmodel(private val repository:FlashcardRepository) : ViewModel() {

    // Using LiveData and caching what allWords returns has several benefits:
    // - We can put an observer on the data (instead of polling for changes) and only update the
    //   the UI when the data actually changes.
    // - Repository is completely separated from the UI through the ViewModel.
    val allWords: LiveData<List<FlashcardPair>> = repository.allWords.asLiveData()

    /**
     * Launching a new coroutine to insert the data in a non-blocking way
     */
    fun insertCards(pair:FlashcardPair) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(pair)
    }

    fun deleteCards(pair:FlashcardPair) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.deleteCard(pair)
    }
}

class WordViewModelFactory(private val repository:FlashcardRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(FlashCardViewmodel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return FlashCardViewmodel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

The following are the Layout files incorporated for Fragment [ToLearnFlashCards] responsible for displaying cards that we saved in QuestionsFragment.

to_learn_flashacards.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flash_tablebar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Do the practise " />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/emojiBounce"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_width="34dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/emoji" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emptyImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recycle_view"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/emptyImage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

recycler_view.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageCardHelper"
            android:src="@drawable/emoji" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/word1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#607d8b" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/word2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#607d8b"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

P.S the initially when the database was created, i was not displaying any images but I modified the data class yesterday. But I don't think it has any issue saving or inserting but somehow there is an issue about displaying wrong image for saved cards.